# multiple list into matrix using bash or (g)awk

Tags: bash, list, matrix, awk

I want to check if hashes of files in file A match certain files. But the files are identified by id's and those id's have a friendly name which is specified in another file (B).

I have a few commands that list the id (1), a command that lists the filename (2) (same order as the id) both from file B. The hashes are from file A.

I want those values in a matrix so I can search and match them like:

Id  Path  Hash

id1  path1 hash1

id2  path2 hash2

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to provide code, but you should be able to solve this problem with [`join`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?join).

So let's say A contains

```
id1<tab>hash1
id2<tab>hash2
```

And B contains

```
id1<tab>path1
id2<tab>path2
```

you can do the following:

```
$ join A B
id1 hash1 path1
id2 hash2 path2
```

Note the first column is used as the key, and this has to be sorted in both files.